# How do you disable built in web browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

is there a way to disable the Visual Studio web browser? I just want it to launch my actual browser when I ctrl-click a hyperlink in a comment.

I see there's a `Web Browser` option in in the `Environment` tab found on`Tools --> Options`...But there doesn't seem to be way to disable it entirely.

Extensions are welcome if there is no native way to do this.

So when I click on a comment (example here shows a comment in an XML file)
[image]

I want it to launch Chrome, not this built-in IE tab in Visual Studio
[image]

---

**Edit** I marked this question as a duplicate of another question. Someone provided this macro:

```
Sub OpenURLInChrome()

    ' Select to end of line
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(True)
    Dim selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection

    ' Find URL within selection
    Dim match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(selection.Text, ".*(http\S+)")

    Dim url As String = ""
    If (match.Success) Then
        If match.Groups.Count = 2 Then
            url = match.Groups(1).Value
        End If
    End If

    ' Remove selection
    selection.SwapAnchor()
    selection.Collapse()

    If (url = String.Empty) Then
        MsgBox("No URL found")
    End If

    'launch chrome with url
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url)
End Sub
```

Then [bind it to a key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0003t62(v=vs.90).aspx) and you use it by setting the cursor at the start of the URL, then pressing your hotkey. Slightly easier than highlighting the whole thing for copy/paste into your browser.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think VS 2010 environment allow you do so, pls go through links, there are some shells which allow you to do so

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2723548-open-links-in-an-actual-browser

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/22ffd60b-5fcf-4ed4-b42c-546d389b4be1/open-url-in-external-browser

If you find a way please post

Comment: edited my question to include a macro that'll launch the browser with the URL in the comment. Not 100% ideal, but I guess that'll be the best we can get.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the aspx page and go to browse with choose the browser, and select as default, as is suggested here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx

they also go into more detail about how to fix it if there isn't an aspx page in your project

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, I don't mean the default browser to debugging an ASP application. I primarily deal with WinForms, and will add a URL in a comment to link to documentation for third-party libraries we use. When I click that URL in the comment, I want it to launch a new tab in my default browser (or a new window, if there's not one open) **instead of it opening up a tab that emulates IE within VS**

Comment: unfortunately i think @kh_s might actually be right...for that, there may not be a good way to do what you're trying to, outside of what was suggested :(